# angular2 after installing bootstrap 4.0.0alpha popper.js issue

Tags: angular

I am working on angular2 project, i installed bootstrap using 
    npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3

and then i have this problem ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in
>   'C:\Users\Bashar\Documents\mont\saleapp\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'
>   @ ./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 7:100-120  @
>   ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts  @ multi event-source-polyfill
>   webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true
>   ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts

Comment: Do you use Angular-CLI?

Comment: yes i use it in my project

Comment: Try adding ```"scripts": ["path to popper.js"]``` in the "apps" property in the .angular-cli.json file

Comment: I don't know its path, how can i know it.

Comment: If you install a module with ```npm install``` it will be installed in the "node_modules" folder in your project root directory. Search for the popper.js file in the bootstrap folder. If it is not there, try installing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing popper.js by the following command:

> npm install popper.js --save